# Sortorder in org-mode journal

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When creating an entry in my journal every new entry is added at the top of the day. I expected it to be inserted at the bottom. This behaviour started when I added asterisks to the template:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
    '(
        ("j" "Journal Entry" plain
              (file+datetree "~/orgmode/journal.org")
              "**** %U %^{Description}  %^g\n%?"
              :empty-lines 1)
```

))

Why are these influencing the insert order? How can I reverse that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old, but I suppose by now you've figured out it can't be done. Apparently the date trees operate this way. An answer from the org-mode mailing list: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2015-07/msg00414.html